# The simplest way to let clients edit pages

Tags: editor

I'm building a wordpress site for a client. I want to let him edit pages (just so he won't bother me), but I know that going to /wp-admin and entering a password, and than navigatin in the dashboard is way beyond his reach.

I need to think of a really simple way to let him  edit pages. preferably something on the page. But of course, I don't want anything weird to appear to regular users...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [`Front End Editor`](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/front-end-editor/) plugin that allows administrators to edit content in-place. If you don't like that in particular try [`8 WordPress Plugins that enable posting and editing from the front-end`](http://wpmu.org/8-wordpress-plugins-that-enable-posting-and-editing-from-the-front-end/) Logging in is still a must. You can login from front as well, though.
See:

1. http://devilsworkshop.org/wordpress-login-form-front/
2. http://pippinsplugins.com/creating-custom-front-end-registration-and-login-forms/
3. http://www.wprecipes.com/add-a-login-form-on-your-wordpress-theme
4. see how http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-login.php WordPress does it

Answer (score 1):

I would try to educate the client on the basics so they could use the regular editor. It's actually quite simple for even the most tech challenged. You could always provide a link to the post-editor page: `http://yoursite.com/wp-admin/post-new.php` then when they will be re-directed to the add post screen after credentials are entered. If you can send an e-mail you should be able to navigate the wp-admin panel. You can go to Screen Options and disable all but the necessary features to simplify it even more.

Another alternative would be to try a desktop post editor: http://www.qumana.com/

I think you may be underestimating your clients abilities. If WordPress hasn't been mucked up by plug-ins and hacks it's UI is about as simple as it gets.

Answer (score -1):

You can post via Email:
It takes some configuration, in settings:

Settings > Writing.

Basically you configure wordpress to read a dedicated email account.

Its all here:

[codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_to_your_blog_using_email)